# Provide ArrayPool object to JsonOutputFormatter constructor

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

After upgrading from .net RC2 to RTM I find I need to supply a parameter to a constructor of JsonOutputFormatter that derives from ArrayPool.  How do I get this object? I am newing JsonOutputFormatter manually because I need to configure ReferenceLoopHandling.

Only other related info I could find is this:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4562

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddMvc();
        var formatterSettings = JsonSerializerSettingsProvider.CreateSerializerSettings();
        formatterSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        JsonOutputFormatter formatter = new JsonOutputFormatter(formatterSettings, ???);

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonOutputFormatter>();
            options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, formatter);
        });

        //etc...
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var formatter = new JsonOutputFormatter(formatterSettings, ArrayPool<Char>.Shared);
```

[Source](https://wildermuth.com/2016/06/27/Converting-ASP-NET-Core-1-0-RC2-to-RTM-Bits)

In the comments:

> The JsonOutputFormatter now needs a ArrayPool when creating it, you
>   can pass in ArrayPool.Shared.

I also noticed there is a .Create() method on ArrayPool.

```
var formatter = new JsonOutputFormatter(formatterSettings, ArrayPool<Char>.Create());
```