# IsoDateTimeConverter added to .NET API breaks default model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, asp.net-core

I was having an issue with my .NET Core API where when DateTimes were serializes, it would leave off milliseconds if the value was 0.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193281/force-json-net-to-include-milliseconds-when-serializing-datetime-even-if-ms-com/18196088?noredirect=1) question explains the issue.  I added the following to my .NET Core Startup class and it resolved the issue such that when I did a `GET`, all dates would be formatted correctly:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        var settings = options.SerializerSettings;
        var dateConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff"
        };
        settings.Converters.Add(dateConverter);
    });
```

After implementing this, I found that it broke default model bindings elsewhere.  For example, I have a `POST` endpoint that accepts the following viewmodel:

```
public class PatientRegistrationViewModel
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Previously I was passing the following JSON data in the request body which it bound successfully:

```
{
    dateOfBirth: '1981-04-18'
}
```

After implementing the date converter above, the viewmodel equals null in my controller.

Comment: Did you maybe just forget the `'Z'` at the end of the `DateTimeFormat` string?

Comment: @haindl Unfortunately, that didn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick solution is to introduce and use `WriteOnlyIsoDateTimeConverter`:

```
public class WriteOnlyIsoDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }
}
```

By overriding [`CanRead`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanRead.htm) to return false, the model binder should continue to use the currently built-in date parsing while using the converter for output formatting.

Another option might be to replace the `JsonOutputFormatter` as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38084437/3744182).

Comment: `WriteOnlyIsoDateTimeConverter` FTW!